Some questions that I had when looking through HTSK Lesson 25
When using 에서 with 아무, I noticed it was 아무 데서 not 아무 데에서. Are both of these fine to use? And also, as a general rule, when can 에서 be shortened to 서?
The website states that 누구나 means “everyone”. But when I googled the meaning, most websites said it meant “anyone”. So does it mean “everyone” or “anyone”? If it means “anyone”, then what is the difference between 아무나 and 누구나?
When using 마다, I noticed that there weren’t any particles attached to the noun that it was modifying. For example, 학생마다 달라요 = Each student is different. Are all particles dropped when using 마다? Or is it just the subject, topic, and object particles?

It looks like these are 3 unrelated question. Please consider putting different questions in different posts.


We don't use 아무데에서.

example - 아무데서나 막말하지 마라.

it seems 데 have 에's meaning already.
('데'라는 말에 '에'라는 뜻이 이미 들어 있는 것으로 느껴집니다)

i could't explain it well(sorry). you can just learn by example.
18세 이상 아무나(no, don't use here)/누구나(yes, you can use here) 투표할 수 있습니다.
아무나(yes)/누구나(no) 만나고 다니면 안돼.
아무나 오세요/누구나 오셔도 됩니다.

마다는 명사 뒤에 붙는 조사입니다. 명사(noun)-마다.



아무 is a determiner meaning "any" in a positive phrase and "no" in a negative one, as in 아무 때에나 오세요 (Come anytime) and 아무 일도 없어요 ( Nothing's the matter),  With certain common nouns, it also creates a single word form as in 아무데 (anywhere) and 아무것 (anything).  So 아무데 without the space is the right spelling and both 아무데에서 and 아무데서 are correct forms, but in speech we say 아무데서 in most cases.  The same /e/ sounds in 데 and 에 tend to combine into one syllable in speech.  In other cases, like 아무 곳에서 which has the same meaning, we say it in full because 아무 곳서 sounds too abrupt and unnatural (but some people might say it like that too).  There is no strict rule about what can be contracted and what can't.

아무나 is closer to "anyone" and 누구나 to "everyone" although they don't have as neat a distinction as those English words do. 아무 is also important as the phrase for "no" (in 아무도 form) because Korean doesn't really have any other word for "no".




이 행사에는 아무나 와도 돼 = Anyone can come to this event.
누구나 어려움을 겪게 된다 = Everyone will encounter difficulties.
학교에 갔는데 아무도 없었다 = I went to the school but there was no one.

Another word for "everyone" or "all" is 모두.  It can combine with 다 (all - (mostly) adverbial) for emphasis.

누구나 (다) 자기만의 비밀이 있다 = 모두 (다) 자기만의 비밀이 있다.



마다 is a particle primarily creating an adverbial phrase.  You typically don't add another particle like 에 after 마다, but this is not a strict rule and you could add a particle in certain cases.  There are many common adverbial phrases (때, 쯤) which can work with the particle 에 but also without it.



건물 마다 플래카드가 걸려 있다 = Every building has a placard hanging from it.
건물 마다에 플래카드가 걸려 있다 = Same. 에 is not required but you can still use it.
해가 질 때(에) 수업이 끝났다 = The class ended when the sun was going down.
다섯 시 쯤(에) 만나자 = Let's meet around five o'clock.


